# How to finalize manual and automation scenarios during sprint

Tags: test-management, test-automation-framework

I have to finalize manual and automation scenarios and give it to the client at the start of the sprint. How to finalize manual and automation scenarios in this scenario?

Comment: Welcome. What do you mean how to finish it? Why not? What's holding you back from finishing it?

Comment: Why vote to close after only 1 hour? Let's try to be a welcoming community and give the OP a chance to clarify before voting to close.

Comment: @LeeJensen https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98022/248731. If you think it should be closed, vote to close it - it's not an irretrievable state, and the OP gets prompted to edit for reopening.

Comment: Surely this encourages new people to raise questions in near future! And by the way...just downvoting without giving a reason is not polite. This guy is new - pavelsman did the rigth way, asked him a question and giving him a chance to modify/add his question.We should do the same.

Comment: Upvoted since this hopefully can lead to an interesting discussion

Answer (score 1):

Note that [a test is a performance, not an artifact.](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/1346)
One does not "delivers a test".

I can interpret your question in two ways:

1 - An estimation problem: You feel you don't have the tools and skills to understand your scope and grasp an idea of the effort necessary to do a professional job, although probably you are capable of doing the work itself.

2 - A communication problem: You don't have the skill to communicate properly with some person that matters what the results of your investigations were (aka testing).

An answer to both problems will be: It depends on your context (which we can help if you give more details).

Generally speaking, for starters, I would suggest Bob Martin ["Effective Estimation (or: How not to Lie)"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eisuQefYw_o) talk ([here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sSE6X01EZ14) is a nugget of this presentation) for the problem (1) and Michael Bolton's "[Breaking the Test Case Addiction](https://www.developsense.com/blog/2019/01/breaking-the-test-case-addiction-part-1/)" 9-part blog post series, where he talks about the problem of considering tests/testing as artifact generation and alternative ways to understand and communicate your testing (as a performance).